# Website directory permission changed automatically

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions

My Website directory permission changed automatically after few days. There is always another php file that i think causing the issue. I have open this php file and there was lot of malicious content.
Every time i delete this file and change permission to run my website but same happens again after few days.
How i can prevent this issue?
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: may be your site is hacked. Scan your website with https://sucuri.net/. Remove all the malicious code from reported files. Also change your `ftp, cpanel, admin password`.

Comment: I have scan my website, remove malicious content many times but this issue keep happening.

Comment: if you have a file that keeps reappearing after deleting it, you have a vulnerability somewhere in your site that is allowing someone or more likely a bot to put that file back in place.  I've seen this recently with a wordpress theme that had a vulnerability.  If you have contributed code (plugins, modules, etc.) in your project, investigate each one for issues, and upgrade where you can.  Start disabling things and monitor it. You're going to have to do some investivative work to find this out.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer. It will help me to fix this issue.